# convert string to TitleCase, SentenceCase, UpperCase and LowerCase but ignore case if words are inside "quotation marks"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am using visual studio 11.0 and in .Net web programming I want to convert a string inputed from TextBox1 to TitleCase, sententenceCase, UpperCase and lowercase by selecting from RadioButtonList1 and show the result in Label1.Text .But I don't want my words which are inside quotation marks to be converted. Example “ASP.NET", "Ph.D" and "xyz".
I have done coding for title case, uppercase and lowercase but i want this code to be ignored/skipped or filtered whereever "quites" comes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;

 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

  }
  private string ConvertToTitleCase(string val)
  {
  string returnString = string.Empty;

System.Globalization.CultureInfo info = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

TextInfo textInfo = info.TextInfo;

returnString = textInfo.ToTitleCase(val);

return returnString;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "a")
    {
Label1.Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox1.Text);
Label1.Text = ConvertToTitleCase(TextBox1.Text);

TextBox1.Text.Equals(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "b")
    {
Label1.Text = "you have selected b";
    }
else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "c")
    {
Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToUpper();
    }
else
Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToLower();

}
```

I need a hint or code which will ignore TitleCase, SentenceCase, UpperCase and LowerCase If..
 my strring is inside "quotes".

Example:

String TextBox1 =  hellO thIs is "asp.net". you ARE in "B.Tech" and welcome To "HCT".

Output:

TitleCase: Hello This Is "asp.net". You Are In "B.Tech" And Welcome To "HCT".

SentenceCase: Hello this is "asp.net". You are in "B.Tech" and welcome to "HCT".

UpperCase: HELLO THIS IS "asp.net". YOU ARE IN "B.Tech" AND WELCOME TO "HCT".

LowerCase: hello this is "asp.net". you are in "B.Tech" and welcome to "HCT".

Comment: ok... and [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: My question is clear I think

Comment: I don't mean to argue with you, but the question is not that clear. Can please you show some code that you have written that shows what you are doing and what exactly does not work? Also, considering you are a new user and a user with over 8K reputation (@Blachshma) makes a suggestion, you should probably heed the suggestion.

Comment: There's literally not even a question in the post. How could it possibly be clear?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions (@Blachshma) and (@Shai Cohen)

Comment: Do you want some other coder to write the code for you?

Comment: No actually I have written the code and for everything and trying to post it here but this site giving me error while I am posting my codes for you people to suggest me what should I do next?  I really apreciate if you let me understand how the things work?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a string contains method it returns a boolean. You could check whether the string contains quotes then you could split the string on the quote and convert the bits you want to and leave the rest as is. I hope I am understanding correctly if not I apologize.

Document for string contains.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx
Document for string split.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Hope this helps.

Just playing around with that class you posted haven’t used that one before.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

  public class FilterString{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
      TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

      string textBoxText = "tEsting To upPerCasE 'STAYCAPS'";
      string filterdTextForLabel = textInfo.ToTitleCase(textBoxText) ;
      Console.WriteLine(filterdTextForLabel);

   }
}
```

This using single quotes it appears it returns the results like you would like them.

output:  Testing To Uppercase 'STAYCAPS'

But what I was thinking is you could do some filtering before you make the conversion assign a variable for the text input then split the string on the quote and anything in the middle portion leave the same the rest you could title case. Let me know if you cannot get it to work I'll make a more in-depth response. :D

Comment: I have added this class in my program so that it accept titlecase conversion

Comment: Using System.Globalization;

Comment: Label1.Text=System.Globalization.cultureInfo.currentCuture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox1.Text);

Comment: Label1.Text=ConvertToTitleCase(TextBox1.Text);

Comment: I used your code @vikingben but unfortunately I was not able to get any out put from Console.WriteLine(variable);

Comment: http://www14.0zz0.com/2013/03/28/10/338656667.png

http://www14.0zz0.com/2013/03/28/10/686176257.png

http://www14.0zz0.com/2013/03/28/10/112475310.png

Comment: I just ran the code in an online compiler in the main method  to test it. For the web app you would need to set the Label1.text = to the filteredTextForLabel variable also it would need to run in an event method or if you are looking for it to update client side you would need to do a similar implementation in javascript or jquery.

Comment: Thanks vikingben its working only for the itleCase. But I want to work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
private delegate string ConvertFunc(string input);

private string ModifyString(string input, ConvertFunc conversion)
{
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, "\".*?\"");
    int lastPos = 0;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        int currentPos = match.Index;
        string toConvert = input.Substring(lastPos, currentPos - lastPos);
        string converted = conversion(toConvert);
        stringBuilder.Append(converted);
        stringBuilder.Append(match.Value);
        lastPos = currentPos + match.Length;
    }

    if (lastPos < input.Length)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(conversion(input.Substring(lastPos)));
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

private string ToUpper(string toConvert)
{
    return toConvert.ToLower();
}
```

Then call ModifyString method from your code:

```
string modifiedString = ModifyString("This can be converted \"This cannot be converted\"", ToUpper);
```

Comment: I am gettting compiler error message: Expected class, delegates, enum, interface, or struct.

Comment: Can you please update my codes which I posted. Because I am beginner and don't have idea to workwith different classes.  Thanks @Petr Behensky

Comment: You can use following instead of Func:
private delegate string ConvertFunc(string input);
Then ModifyString method will be:
private string ModifyString(string input, ConvertFunc conversion)
{...

Comment: Microsof Visual (premium) Studio 2012

Comment: It is not .NET Framework. Go to your project properties and check Target framework field

Comment: The type or namespace "StringBuilder" and "MatchCollection" could not found

Comment: Do you want from me to write your app?
Check documentation.

Comment: I can't see my project properties under project in menu bar. Only "manage NuGet Packages" and " Enable NuGet Packages" are there.

Comment: Can you please develop my codes? Your code is still notwoking with because undeclares namespaces.

Comment: I am using visual studio 11.0 files(x86)

Comment: your code is for sure correct but I am a beginner and don't have idea to use your code and implement it on my project. If you edit my codes I would be thankful to you.